# Google Maps Restarting Drawing Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a website that this a one page form with a Google Map as one of the form steps. The Google Map is created using their JavaScript API.

The user enters their address and the map loads that address, where the user can then draw a polygon over their roof and I get the area of that polygon.

When the user enters the website the map has an overlay on top of it with an input and a button. After the address is inputed the map loads the address and the overlay disappears.

The map also has two custom buttons, one to clear the map and a back button, which shows the overlay again and the user can input a new address.

Here is all of my code that deals with loading, and clearing the map:

initMap function, which also creates the two buttons.

```
function initMap() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    streetViewControl: false,
    center: {
        lat: 40.2474449,
        lng: -5.7720482
    }
});
var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var centerControl = new MapControl(centerControlDiv);
centerControlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
centerControlDiv.className = "mapControl";
map.setTilt(0);
}
```

showMap function which is called when the overlay is submitted:

```
function showMap() {
var zipCode = document.getElementById("postalCode").value;
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': zipCode + " España"
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        allowDrawing();
        $(".mapCover").fadeOut(300);
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
}
```

allowDrawing function which allows the user to draw on the map:

```
function allowDrawing() {
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: 'rgba(0, 212, 153, 0.4)',
        strokeColor: "rgb(0, 212, 153)",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        editable: true
    }
});
drawingManager.setMap(map);
polygon && polygon.setMap(null);

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (plgn) {
    polygon = plgn;
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    calcArea(polygon);
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', function () {
        calcArea(polygon);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function () {
        calcArea(polygon);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'remove_at', function () {
        calcArea(polygon);
    });
});
}
```

The clear map button just calls allow drawing function and the back button calls the show map function.

Because I only want one polygon to be drawn at a time and the polygon is editable, when the polygon is complete I do this: `drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);` so that drawing is now disabled and the user can edit the shape.

My problem is that everything works as it should, except for when the back button is pressed when there is no polygon is present. When that happens `drawingMode` is not getting set for `drawingManager` and the user can keep drawing as many shapes as they want. This is a very bizarre problem as it doesn't occur when the clear map function is called or if the user presses the back button without clearing the map.

I tried multiple things, such as removing any listeners of drawing manager, but nothing is working except for one thing. Which is to call the initMap function every time the user submits the overlay.

This doesn't seem like a smart thing to do, calling initMap over and over again, as all I need to do is to center the map on the new address and enable drawing again.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ckpyb81/3/) showing the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a SO code snippet)

Comment: Do you have a public URL (or create with https://jsbin.com) so we could try to debug it?

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to a jsfiddle where the problem still occurs.

Comment: When click on `Back` button, you should set the `drawingManager`'s `drawingMode` to `null`.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory Yes, that worked. I can't believe I didn't try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `drawingManager's` `drawingMode` to `null` when the back button is clicked worked.